# Unable to set Object instance as selected item of JComboBox with Renderer

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I have a DAOImplementation class with the method definition below.

```
@Override
    public Registration getRegistrationInfoById(int aRegistrationId) {
        String SQL = "{CALL getRegistrationInfoById(?)}";
        Registration aRegistration = new Registration();
        try (Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
                CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(SQL);) {
            cs.setInt(1, aRegistrationId);
            try (ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();) {
                while (rs.next()) {

                    int gradeLevel = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(RegistrationTable.GRADELEVEL));
                    aRegistration.setGradeLevel(gradeLevel);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getErrorCode() + "\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return aRegistration;

    }//end of method
```

This returns an integer value of Grade Level (1,2,3,4,5,6,7...so on...) which I've verified because I tried printing the output returned by `aRegistration.getGradeLevel();`

Now my problem is with my `JComboBox`. I have set a `ListCellRenderer` for my `JComboBox` which holds all the `GradeLevel` values

```
public class JComboBoxRenderer_GradeLevel extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {

    public JComboBoxRenderer_GradeLevel() {
        this.setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Object> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof GradeLevel) {
            this.setText("" + ((GradeLevel) value).getGradelevel());
        } else {
            this.setText("--");
        }

        if (isSelected) {
            this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            this.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            this.setBackground(list.getBackground());
            this.setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

And looks like this `JComboBox` as expected. (`GradeLevel` model is renderered to simply show an int value of gradelevel), `((GradeLevel) value).getGradelevel());`returns an integer value.

[image]

I understand that even when `JComboBox` has its renderer that displays an integer value of `GradeLevel` by using `((GradeLevel)value).getGradeLevel()`, the actual value on the `JComboBox` is still treated as instance of `GradeLevel` or object. But not a `String` or `int`.

So my problem is when I try to set the selected value to an int value, it won't change the selected value of the `JComboBox`. Nothing happens when I use `setSelectedItem();`

This is what I tried to do for the GUI.

```
//Grade Level
    GradeLevelDaoImpl gldi = new GradeLevelDaoImpl();
    List<GradeLevel> gradeLevels = gldi.getAllGradeLevelsInfo();
    DefaultComboBoxModel gradeLevelModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(gradeLevels.toArray());
    jcmbGradeLevel.setModel(gradeLevelModel);
    jcmbGradeLevel.setRenderer(new JComboBoxRenderer_GradeLevel());
    jcmbGradeLevel.setSelectedIndex(-1);

GradeLevel gradeLevel = new GradeLevel();
gradeLevel.setGradelevel(registration.getGradeLevel());
jcmbGradeLevel.setSelectedItem(gradeLevel); //PROBLEM HERE, it doesn't change
```

`JOptionPane` displays this.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"GradeLevel: "+gradeLevel);
```

[image]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"GradeLevel: "+gradeLevel.getGradeLevel());
```

[image]

It doesn't seem to be able to compare the object I'm trying to set it to(`gradeLevel`) with the objects `JComboBox` has(`gradeLevels`). Notice the singular and plural.

How do I manipulate the **types** so that `setSelectedItem()` will match with what the `JComboBox` have?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to make this work using objects, you will need to override the class's (`Registration`) `equals` and `hashcode` methods, so that any object with a `gradeLevel` of `1` will be equal so, and so forth

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to do a quick google on equals and hashcode overriding. So how I'm getting this is that I only need to do it on Registration class? :D Right? Still reading the info I googled. Haven't heard of it before.

Comment: @p3ace, `I only need to do it on Registration class?` - you implement those methods on the Object class that you add to the combo box. If your renderer is expecting `GradeLevel` objects, then that tells me you should be implementing these methods in the `GradeLevel` class.

Comment: @camickr Oh yeah sorry, I was thinking of a different class. Kind of mixed up thoughts on what to do next. :P

Comment: `Object#equals` (and `Object#hashcode`) are a very common and widely used concept in Java, it basically states that while `objA != objB` because they are two different instances `objA.equals(objB)` can return `true` if they contain the same properties (as defined by the developer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this by using different instances of the object, but with the same properties, then you need to override the class's `equals` and `hashcode` methods, so that the combination of properties are unique.  This is very important, this is a relationship expectation that any object which is `equal` to another will have the same `hashcode`

This is a really quick example and I used by IDE's auto generation process (because I'm lazy), but, if your `Registration` class has other properties which should be considered when comparing to instances of the class, you will need to modify it to support them (again, any good IDE should be able to do this)

```
public class Registration {
    private int gradeLevel;

    public Registration(int gradeLevel) {
        this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
    }


    public int getGradeLevel() {
        return gradeLevel;
    }

    public void setGradeLevel(int gradeLevel) {
        this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 73 * hash + this.gradeLevel;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Registration other = (Registration) obj;
        if (this.gradeLevel != other.gradeLevel) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Then using something like...

```
Registration a = new Registration(1);
Registration b = new Registration(1);
Registration c = new Registration(2);

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
System.out.println(a.equals(c));
System.out.println(b.equals(c));
```

will print...

```
true
false
false
```

which shows us that the code is working.

Once you get this setup, you should then be able to change the selected item by creating an instance of `Registration`, seeding it with the required properties and passing it to the `JComboBox`.

This is very important and very common concept used a lot within Java, well worth taking the time to learn and understand

Comment: I'm still working on absorbing the information. Will probably take me time to absorb. Will take your advice, will learn this. I appreciate that example. Examples always help me understand new concepts easier. Thanks.